# How can I create a list with a pop up textfield?

Tags: list, listview, flutter, dart, charts

May I ask something.

I created a button with a textfield pop up.

But the input from the text field should create a list which I can then use later for a chart...

[here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZzCU.png)

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. please add more information to understand your problem and also add all minimal code which replicate your issue not snapshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you can implement !
Modify this as your requirment !

```
TextEditingController tc;
  List<String> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tc = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
        onPressed: (){
          showPopup();
        }
      ),
      body:ListView.builder(
        itemCount:list.length,
      itemBuilder:(con,ind)=>
        ListTile(
        title:Text(list[ind],
                  style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
        )
      )
    );
  }

  void showPopup() {
    tc.text = '';
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (con) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Popup Tilte'),
                content: TextField(
                    controller: tc,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Field Title',
                    )),
                actions: [
                  FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Add'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (tc.text.trim().isNotEmpty) addToList();
                        Navigator.of(con).pop();
                      })
                ]));
  }

  void addToList() {
    setState(() {
      list.add(tc.text.trim());
    });
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]